# Freezing the first column in a table, and maintaining a consistent height where the header row is set to wrap whitespace?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table in HTML which has the following properties:

- The first column is frozen
- The text on the header row is wrapped

Sounds simple, but I'm having an issue where the first column in the header row has the wrong height, I would like it to match the rest of the row. Here is an example:

```css
tr th {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}

tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-column {
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-column.header {
    background-color: red;
}

.second-column {
    padding-left: 145px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first-column header">Aaaaa aaaaa</th>
                        <th class="second-column">Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you run the above, you will see that the height of the **Aaaaa aaaaa** column is not in line with the rest of the row. Setting the height of this to 100% sets that column to the height of the table, not the row. I'm hoping the answer is simple, and I've just missed some obvious piece of CSS, but I'm a bit stumped so some help would be appreciated.

One solution I have is to use Javascript so set the height dynamically, something like this:

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            var firstColumnHeader = document.getElementById('first-column-header');
            var secondColumnHeader = document.getElementById('second-column-header');

            firstColumnHeader.style.height = secondColumnHeader.clientHeight;
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="first-column-header" class="first-column header">Aaaaa aaaaa</th>
                            <th id="second-column-header" class="second-column">Bbb bbb bbb</th>
```

I would like to avoid Javascript if possible however, this seems like something I should be able to do with CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already concluded that the position:absolute doesn't work because the table doesn't apply the used row height to an abspos cell as it would with an inflow cell. The browser-imposed `display:table-cell` might even be ignored for abspos cells, I'm not sure.

Anyway, try the new-ish `position: sticky` with `left: xx` as below. With this you don't need to duplicate the width in second column's padding to make room for first column.

```css
tr th {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}

tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-column {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-column.header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first-column header">Aaaaa aaaaa</th>
                        <th class="second-column">Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                        <th>Bbb bbb bbb</th>
                        <th>Cc cccc</th>
                        <th>Ddddd dd dd ddddd</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>Ffff</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td class="second-column">dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                        <td>dsfgsgs gsdfg</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```